# bootstrap datepicker option doesn't seem work (datepicker by vitalets)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I included everything but it doesn't seem work with the options, no example for a newbiew is a pain.. help..

html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control  datepicker" id="datepicker" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
```

js

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        todayHighlight: true
});
```

github reference: https://github.com/vitalets/bootstrap-datepicker#autoclose

Comment: ensure your input has an id of `datepicker` or change the jQuery selector to match your input

Comment: I did.. the calendar showed but the options doesn't work..

Comment: Post HTML code aswell.

Comment: Which options don't work? Things like `todayHighlight` require the css to be included as well. The JS only applies a class to the today date, the actual highlighting is done by css. I have a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UdgPx/. See how it compares to your setup

Comment: no, the calendar show but the option not working, the only option which is working is date-date-format in the html, i tried other option that way, but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine,

check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjtNY/332/) the datepicker is getting closed when I select a date.

```
autoclose: true  //this will work with vitalets
```

I guess the following is the possible reason:

1) Might given wrong *bootstrap.datepicker.js*

```
<script src="http://vitalets.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Make sure your path is right

Answer (score 8):

**todayBtn: true** directs the button to only bring today into view, not select it. If you want the button to actually change the date selected, use:

```
todayBtn: "linked"
```

See it from: https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/314

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
.on('changeDate', function(ev){                 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('hide');
});
```

**Update:**

`autoclose` works fine with the datepicker present in the following repo:

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: this repo is changing, you should give the version number