# ASP.Net MVC bootstrap-datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Have scoured Google for a solution but the closest I could find ([Bootstrap Datepicker Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058725/bootstrap-datepicker-not-working)) doesn't resolve the issue.

AFAIK, I'm loading the necessary JS and CSS references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

<link rel=" stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css">
<link rel=" stylesheet" href="~/Content/datepicker.min.css">
<link rel=" stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css">
```

In my view, I have the following HTML input:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" data-provide="datepicker" class="form-control datepicker" />
```

And I have this simple Javascript at the end of my view code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            orientation: "bottom auto",
            daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
            todayHighlight: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

But for some reason, the datepicker doesn't show up.

Curiously, if I remove `input id="datepicker"` then the datepicker shows up and I am able to select dates and see them reflected in the input textbox (meaning it's using the class datepicker to bind, but why is it using #id notation?) **HOWEVER**, when doing this the options aren't being rendered, i.e., days 0 and 6 aren't being ignored, the position of the datepicker dropdown isn't at the bottom of the input element, today isn't highlighted and it doesn't "autoclose" on date selection.

Help?

Comment: What happens if you remove `data-provide="datepicker"`?

Comment: @TimLewis still doesn't work :( Nothing loads.

Comment: By the way, no errors in my Console when checking developer tools in Chrome.

Comment: Hmm. I was pretty sure `data-provide` autosets the options based on other `data-` attributes, but I guess not. Do you have to have a JSFiddle set up for this? That would help with the debugging. Also, which library is this? eternicodes or eonasdan? Or some other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to straight-copy the code from the JSFiddle linked to here: [bootstrap datepicker option doesn't seem work (datepicker by vitalets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363398/bootstrap-datepicker-option-doesnt-seem-work-datepicker-by-vitalets) and it works now. Turns out it didn't like the `orientation:"` option, removing that resolved the problem. Not sure why that doesn't work though.